# Twitter OAuth get request token

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

so - tearing my hair out here

im sending this a POST to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

my Authorisation header is

```
OAuth oauth_callback="splat%3A%2F%2F",
oauth_consumer_key="Fh71vIGgcR9zJO7eF1Rc4NC5t",
oauth_nonce="c0ec4fcb6b84b089821a4eea187e8dbc0b4629fb1760203805304cb25193b72f%2C",
oauth_signature="OTkyYmI2NDM1MTc4YjY0OTQwYzYwZTUwNWEyZGVkZDI3MzYyNjBkZg%3D%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1414442911001",
oauth_version="1.0"
```

and my base string used to generate this was

POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dsplat%253A%252F%252F%26oauth_consumer_key%3DFh71vIGgcR9zJO7eF1Rc4NC5t%26oauth_nonce%3Dc0ec4fcb6b84b089821a4eea187e8dbc0b4629fb1760203805304cb25193b72f%252C%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1414442911001%26oauth_version%3D1.0

i keep getting a 401 however, my example seems to match any examples i can find

any help/obvious mistakes would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Without your consumer key (and I suggest you don't post it here!), we can't check whether your signature is correct or not.

However you could try verifying your signature using one of the online signature generators such as:

[The LinkedIn OAuth Test Console](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, what fixed it for me was to remove the oauth_callback altogether.
Just specify a callback in the app settings, then it should work.
I know the documentation labels it as required, but somehow with the callback it doesn't work.

Your header should look like this:

```html
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
      oauth_nonce="Lhw1HTTtPojMXTsPNWwlXMp1J8UPST9GftzelvW6rQ6", 
      oauth_signature="zQyHupvnJwFaRPU8IR%2F2axaMFVc%3D", 
      oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
      oauth_timestamp="1415554564", 
      oauth_version="1.0"
```

And your basestring something like this:

```html
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%XXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3DLhw1HTTtPojMXTsPNWwlXMp1J8UPST9GftzelvW6rQ6%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1415554564%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```